# Fullpage.js - auto height sections but scroll to top of section regardless of scroll direction

Tags: fullpage.js

With fullpage.js I'm using fp-auto-height for auto height sections, but also using a nav to auto/smooth scroll sections. If you have a section that is taller than 100vh and scroll DOWN to it, fp aligns the top of the section with the top of the viewport so the extra portion at the bottom is off screen (thumbs up). However, if you scroll UP to it, fp aligns the *bottom* of the section to the bottom of the viewport so the top is offscreen. My headers get cut off.

Any way to get it to always align the top of the section with the top of the viewport when section scrolling (while keeping fp-auto-height)?

This is a situation where the site began with auto scrolling and now the client doesn't want it and I don't feel like removing fp altogether unless I have to.

Comment: As long as you have a last section that is full-screen, that could be relatively easy to customise. Otherwise the problem is that once you reach the bottom of your page you won't be able to scroll to the top of the last or last few sections, as there won't be anything else underneath. So basically, you would be forced to calculate when we are able to scroll to the top of a section and when not based on the window height and your sections height.

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks man! —GavinsBro :)